# Interpolation for Sobolev spaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, semigroups-of-operators, interpolation-spaces

How one can identify the following (complex) interpolation space
$$E_\theta :=[L^2(\Omega), H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)]_\theta,$$
where $\Omega$ is a regular domaine. After research, it seems that this depend on the position of $\theta \in (0,1)$:

for $0<\theta<1/4$, $E_\theta=H^{2\theta}(\Omega)$ and for $1/4 <\theta <1$ we have $E_\theta=H^{2\theta}_0(\Omega)$, while the case $\theta =1/4$ is critical.

Some inclusions are immediate while the others are not. Is there any elegant way to establish such identification?

Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: There is a [answer to a related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280587/interpolation-spaces/280596#280596) with some info, maybe this is sufficiently elegant..

Comment: @Hannes thank you, but this gives just the link to domains of fractional powers and not the explicit characterization depending on $\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a result by R. Seeley: Interpolation in Lp with boundary conditions, Studia Mathematica, 1972.

The main ingredient of the proof is that step functions are pointwise multipliers in Hs for s<1/2.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that the result was already proved by many others, e.g., Fujiwara, Grisvard... I'm looking for an elementary way to do it.

Comment: The book of Lions and Magenes is another reference for this kind of result. But what do you mean by "elementary"? Surely not using pre-calculus only?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I meant not using heavy theories such as $H^\infty$ calculus, or a way that can be generalized to more complex spaces e.g., product spaces.